# Implement a Custom Search Engine built on top of google.com

Tags: javascript, php, html, search, web

I want to build a webpage/ custom search engine that will take user input and then query google for the results, except that with a number of keywords I want to append some predefined strings that ( will be stored in a dictionary/file..).

I tried using a form and then submitting query to google, but I want to do it as beautifully (and much the same way) as [these people have done](http://zlaaatan.com/).
They just append Zlatan at the beginning , I want to append variable strings.

**To show you what I've tried, here is the link to GitHub: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-query.php**

Any useful links, knowledge , suggestions, steps would be heartily appreciated.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried ?

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-query.php

Comment: Why everybody downvoted my question and nobody cared to ven put a single answer or link. Better help that ridicule if you have a bit of time. SO arrogant people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how they do it. Just do the same but append any word from you list of words as you like. It's not clear how you're supposed to select what words to add. Specify that and we can be more helpful.

```
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
  var input = document.getElementById('field');

  form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var redirect = 'https://google.com/search?q=zlatan+' + input.value;

    window.location = redirect;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. People ridicule, nobody helps. Thanks. I want to have a list of 100 or so words which when entered will be appened with a string before being queried. I will build a list with its index being the keywords defined and then keywordlist + list["keyword"], if there is an entry in the list , then string is returned else empty string is returned. (I will have to make a function to do this).

Comment: could you provide a simple HTML page code that just does this. Many Many thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a great Q&A, if your looking for a freelance programmer I think you should look else were. Personally I don't have time to implement your search engin, sorry.